# Kubernetes Ingress rule define multiple DNS name

Tags: kubernetes

I am running bare metal v1.9 cluster. I was able define one DNS name `app1-dev.com` for the ingress rule, Is it possible to define multiple name for the same ingress rule?

like

```
app1-dev.com
appdev.com
```

Here is my rule:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
      name: ingress-dev
      namespace: default
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: app1-dev.com
          http:
            paths:
            - path: /web
              backend:
                serviceName: nginx-svc
                servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use sub-domain wildcards in host field (e.g. `- host: "*.domain.com"`), but there is no way to set multiple values so you have to repeat entire rule for each domain.